# Defining the name of a text/html file like the name of a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame CLI_CAP_X_PROD_AG:

```
      FAMILIA_PRD NUM_CLI CAPITAL_SOL PART_CAP_PER ATRASADA ATR_PER
      A             536     2616925        33.62   467830   17.88
      B             151     1613035        20.72   268223   16.63
```

when I try to save the file using the name of the data.frame I get error:

```
      print(temp,type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE, file = paste(CLI_CAP_X_PROD_AG,"_tab.html", sep=""))
```

because R read the elements of CLI_CAP_X_PROD_AG.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't you need to to put it in a string "CLI_CAP_X_PROD_AG" ?

Comment: What is this `print()` function that apparently takes `type` and `file` arguments? No such arguments are taken by [`print()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html), [`print.default()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.default.html), and [`print.data.frame()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.dataframe.html).

Comment: It's a function from xtable

Comment: I will loop this code as a function over many dataframes so I need that R names each html file using the name of each dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your xtables in a named list and iterate over the list. Demo:

```
library('xtable');
li <- list(t1=xtable(data.frame(a=letters[1:3],b=1:3)),t2=xtable(data.frame(a=letters[4:6],b=4:6)));
names(li);
## [1] "t1" "t2"
li;
## $t1
## % latex table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.7-4 package
## % Fri Jun 19 13:48:30 2015
## \begin{table}[ht]
## \centering
## \begin{tabular}{rlr}
##   \hline
##  & a & b \\
##   \hline
## 1 & a &   1 \\
##   2 & b &   2 \\
##   3 & c &   3 \\
##    \hline
## \end{tabular}
## \end{table}
##
## $t2
## % latex table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.7-4 package
## % Fri Jun 19 13:48:30 2015
## \begin{table}[ht]
## \centering
## \begin{tabular}{rlr}
##   \hline
##  & a & b \\
##   \hline
## 1 & d &   4 \\
##   2 & e &   5 \\
##   3 & f &   6 \\
##    \hline
## \end{tabular}
## \end{table}
##
for (n in names(li)) print(li[[n]],type='html',include.rownames=F,file=paste0(n,'_tab.html'));
file.show('t1_tab.html',pager='cat');
## <!-- html table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.7-4 package -->
## <!-- Fri Jun 19 13:48:34 2015 -->
## <table border=1>
## <tr> <th> a </th> <th> b </th>  </tr>
##   <tr> <td> a </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td> b </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td> c </td> <td align="right">   3 </td> </tr>
##    </table>
##
file.show('t2_tab.html',pager='cat');
## <!-- html table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.7-4 package -->
## <!-- Fri Jun 19 13:48:34 2015 -->
## <table border=1>
## <tr> <th> a </th> <th> b </th>  </tr>
##   <tr> <td> d </td> <td align="right">   4 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td> e </td> <td align="right">   5 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td> f </td> <td align="right">   6 </td> </tr>
##    </table>
##
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. Though I had found another solution.